# AngularJs ng-pattern regex

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I am struggling writing a Regex for angular ng-pattern to validate a form input field.An example of the possible inputs are below

Valid input:

```
@tag1,@tag2,@tag3
@tag1, @tag2, @tag3
@tag1
```

Invalid Input:

```
@tag 1
@tag 1, @tag2, @tag  -3
@ta g1, @t ag2
```

Basically it should allow comma and comma whitespace, but not allow whitespace in between tags.

I have written a REGEX that matches all the invalid input, but when I use this in ng-pattern it does not do the correct validation.

Regex Built: `/((^, @|@\s+)|@*[a-zA-Z0-9]* +[a-zA-Z0-9])/g`
Link: https://regex101.com/r/HMVdLD/1

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why use a regex that matches *invalid* input?

Comment: I tried negating the above expression. That does not seem to work either.

Comment: Look, [`/^@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,\s*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/REqF0G/1) should match all valid ones, and it is much easier. Put it into the `ng-pattern` attribute value (`ng-pattern="/pattern/"`). What about leading/trailing whitespace? Do you want it to be allowed in your input field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest defining a pattern to match *valid* inputs, like

```
ng-pattern="/^@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,\s*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/REqF0G/1)

If you want to disallow leading and trailing whitespace, add `ng-trim="false"`.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `@` - a literal `@` symbol
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ alphanumerics
- `(?:,\s*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `,` - comma
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `@[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - same as above
- `$` -  end of string.